# MongoDB University NodeJS Issues

Tags: mongodb

I have been struggling with as assignment in MongoDB University after looking through all of the documentation for MongoDB and trying to put together every query I could think of. I am stuck on homework 2.4. I wish I knew somewhere else to ask this, but I have struggled with this one for 2 days now.

How many documents in our video.movieDetails collection list just the following two genres: "Comedy" and "Crime" with "Comedy" listed first.

The genres are listed like so:

```
genres: [
    "Country",
    "Adventure",
    "Drama",
    "Crime"
]
```

I don't usually ask for people to answer questions for me, but this one has me completely stumped on the query that would get me to the point where I can get the correct result. I have tried projections, comparisons, etc. with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be a lot simpler than you think.  You can just do:

```
db.collection_name.count({
    genres:[
        "Comedy",
        "Crime"
    ]
})
```

The criteria that genres contains only those two elements and the order is already specified means you don't have to do any special array operations.

Comment: Shows how much I still have to learn about Mongo :-) Thank you so much for your help in pushing me forward.